# How to set unique style to tool tip attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have tool tip attribute in my table, I want to set width to this attribute related to my column width, so I have different size tool tips. I have different column widths and I want to set width to the tool tip based on my column width, I mean how can I access data-md-tooptip attribute (tool tip element) through JavaScript and ad style like `document.querySelector([data-md-tooltip]).style.width = "000px"`

```css
[data-md-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

[data-md-tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(data-md-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  
  /*width: 360px;*/
  top: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 8px;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: top;
  background: #232F34;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  z-index: 2;
}

[data-md-tooltip]:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<td class="mdc-data-table__cell" data-md-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since">
  <div class="long-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been      the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
  </div>
</td>
<hr>
<!-- Here I want different tool tip width -->
<td class="mdc-data-table__cell" data-md-tooltip="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since">
  <div class="long-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been      the industry's standard dummy text ever since,L
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelector` requires a String as a parameter so you need to write

```
document.querySelector('[data-md-tooltip]').style.width = ...
```

But this method will return only the first element matched by that selector: if you need to apply the style to more than one `[data-md-tooltip]` element you need to use `document.querySelectorAll` and walk over the node collection you retrieve (e.g. using the spread `...` operator)

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-md-tooltip]')].forEach((tt) => {
   tt.width = ...
})
```